# Change select options based on another select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I have been recently experimenting with Php and CodeIgniter and created a simple project where you make an order. Now on the order form there are some options where the user selects what he/she wants from dropdown menus. I managed to show the available options from the database, now what I want to do is when the user picks an option from one of the dropdowns menu then one of the next dropdowns to show options is only associated to that pick.

For example to be more specific let's say that the user will buy a phone, first he should pick the brand let's say Samsung, now the next dropdown should only show models that are from Samsung and not from other brands.

What I have done so far is when the user selects the brand then I make a pick of the model of that brand in the next dropdown menu, but if he clicks for more options then all the models of all brands will be available.

I have done that with javascript.

```
    {
        if(x == 1)
        { 
            id_mentese = 1; 
        }

        $('#model option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $('#model').find('option[value='+id_model+']').attr("selected","selected");
        thistext=$('#model option:selected').text();
        $('.form-control').find('button[data-id="model"]').attr("title",thistext);
        $('button[data-id="model"]').find('.filter-option').text('').text(thistext);
    }
```

where x is the id of the brand

Any idea how to do this ?
Also if I could make it so that if the user doesn't pick the brand then the model dopdown shouldn't be active.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<select id="brand">
  <option value="none">-- Select a brand --</option>
  <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
  <option value="htc">HTC</option>
</select>
<select id="cat" style="display:none;">
</select
```

JS

```
var models = [
  ["A","C","M","J","H"],
  ["htc1","htc2","htc3"]
]; //load this from database

$("#brand").change(function(){
  var ind = $("#brand option:selected").index();
  if(ind == 0){
    $("#cat").hide();
  }else{
    $("#cat").empty();
    $.each(models[ind + 1], function(key) {
      $("#cat").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(key));
    });
  }
});
```